# Rotate a scene tile in Godot 4

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I have a decoration layer in my tilemap, one of those decorations is a scene, which needs to be rotated, but godot tilemap only allows rotating normal tiles, not scene tiles. Is there a way to do this either in editor or in script?

The only workaround I could think of would be creating four wrapper scenes that would only contain that scene I want to include, rotated by 90 degrees each, and using those as the tiles. But this adds a lot of "scene clutter" to the project.

Comment: The closest I got so far is by calling update_internals() in _ready, I can load the tilemap prematurely and the access the scene nodes by using get_children. But I am still unable to modify the rotation of the Node2d.